# How to get QGridLayout item by clicked QPoint?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I have grid of QFrames in QGridLayout and a popup menu with some actions, which are targeted on the cell where mouse right click happens. On the implementation of ContextMenuEvent I get clicked QPoint using common event->pos() but how I get access to my correct cell object by that point? Or is there some better alternative solution path for this purpose?

```
void X::contextMenuEvent(QContextMenuEvent* event)
{   // QPoint target = event->pos();
    // TODO: m_gridLayout-> ...
    // myDerivedCell->setSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a bunch of solutions here. The simplest is to go through your widgets, calling `bool QWidget::underMouse () const`. My favorite is this:

```
frame_i->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu);
connect(frame_i, SIGNAL(customContextMenuRequested(QPoint))
        , SLOT(onContextMenu(QPoint)));

...

void X::onContextMenu(const QPoint &pos)
{
    QFrame *w = qobject_cast < QFrame * >(sender());
    ...
}
```